# send a dynamice 3D array to a function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameter-passing

I am early in c++ programming. I want to send a 3D array to a function.same:

```
const int MaxNumberOfLegs=function1();
double D_and_L_Of_Legs[4][2][MaxNumberOfLegs] = {        { {1, 2, 3.4, 4}   , {1, 2, 3, 4} },
                                 { {1, 2, 3, 4.5}   , {1, 2, 3} }, 
                                 { {1.8, 2, 3, 4}   , {1, 2, 3, 4} }, 
                                 { {}   , {} }  
                        };
function2(D_and_L_Of_Legs);
```

and function2 is same:

```
void ProcessImage(double D_and_L_Of_Legs[4][2][MaxNumberOfLegs]){
}
```

in my code, `MaxNumberOfLegs` variable calculate with `function1` and not a const variable. and in c++ when we want to send an array we must write dimention of array.
Now my question is, How can i send 3d array when third dimention is not const??

Comment: That is not a valid C++ array, because `MaxNumberOfLegs` is not a compile-time constant. C++ doesn't support [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: As for how to solve your problem, consider using `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, can you tell me How i can use std::vector in this program? i am early in c++.

Answer (score 0):

This function will do:

```
void ProcessImage(double D_and_L_Of_Legs[][][], int MaxNumberOfLegs){
}
```

And when you want to call, do this:

```
const int MaxNumberOfLegs=function1();
   double D_and_L_Of_Legs[4][2][MaxNumberOfLegs] = {
                                     { {1, 2, 3.4, 4} ,{1, 2, 3, 4} },
                                     { {1, 2, 3, 4.5}   , {1, 2, 3} }, 
                                     { {1.8, 2, 3, 4}   , {1, 2, 3, 4} }, 
                                     { {}   , {} }  
                            };
    function2(D_and_L_Of_Legs,MaxNumberOfLegs);
```

**Alternative method:**

Try to declare `MaxNumberOfLegs` out side the function as a global variable and keep all the code same. ie `int MaxNumberOfLegs=function1();` put this on the top of the code. and inside the function make `MaxNumberOfLegs=function1();`.